# Can a file name be code injectable

Tags: php, file

My PHP web application parses incoming email messages and stores it in MySQL table. After email content is parsed I use MySQL prepared statements to store different email parts such as "To", "From", "Subject", "Body" etc. to prevent any code injections.

If an email has an attachment I would need to store it in a folder and if it is encrypted with PGP to run gpg external command through PGP EXEC function.

This files handling seems to be code injectable, i.e. if someone call an attahcment something like:

**"mydoc.doc mysqldump_to_www_root and_format_all_partitions"**

Maybe I'm wrong. To prevent that I decided to check if the file exists right after its creation like that:

```
//Here I save the file to a folder
$filename = $attachment->filename;
if ($fp = fopen($save_dir.$filename, 'w')) {
    while($bytes = $attachment->read()) {
      fwrite($fp, $bytes);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

//Here I check for injection
If(!is_file($attach_dir.'/'.$filename)) {
    // something wrong, do not proceed
}
```

My OS is Ubuntu with EXT4 file system. Would that shceme save me from possible code injections in email file attachments? Do I need to worry about it in the first place if eventually I want to do the follwoing for example:

```
$cmd = "gpg --passphrase *** '$attachedir/$filename'";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

In other words does storing a file to a disk sanitize/filter the file name or there could be exceptions?

Comment: Why not change the name of the file to a random string, and store both the original name and the random string in your database?

Comment: @ChrisForrence What if the original name has an unwanted code?

Comment: Then the unwanted code gets stored harmlessly as a string in the database table's "original filename" column.  You said you're using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection, and that's the right thing to do.

Comment: Oh eah, that's right!

Comment: ANYTHING is injectable, if you allow external data to used in a context where it becomes executable, or can influence execution directly. `$foo = $_GET['hackme']` is perfectly harmless. Doing `eval($foo)` right afterwords is outright insane.

Comment: @Marc B I understand that. So if I do fopen($foo, 'w'); fwrite, fclose and then I check if(!is_file($foo)) and it exists can I then consider the $foo as a harmless content?

Comment: @Wyzard ... but probably not for exec($cmd, $output) though

Comment: not really, what if `$_GET['hackme'] = '/etc/passwd'`?

Comment: @Marc B Hm... good point!

Comment: you have to determine HOW you're using the data, and what would happen if something malicious came in via that data. There's no "run this function on it and you'll be perfectly safe", because it's literally impossible to do that. A function which performs escaping for SQL injection prevent is utterly useless if the data being escape won't ever be used in an SQL query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has an [`escapeshellarg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function that escapes shell metacharacters in a string to ensure that it's treated as a single argument, not a group of arguments or separate commands.  Use this on the filename when building the command string that you pass to `exec()`.

Comment: If I do $cmd = "gpg --passphrase *** escapeshellarg('$attachedir/$filename')"; $exec($cmd, $output) I get an error as this escapeshellarg gets into gpg bash command line :(

Comment: Right, because that's not calling a function, it's just writing the word "escapeshellarg" in a string literal.  Use `"gpg --passphrase **** " . escapeshellarg($attachedir . "/" $filename)`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right! However it eats up non-ASCII charachters i.e. if I have Russian letters in the filename those gets skipped

Comment: Ok, I've found that's a kind of a bug for escapeshellarg() which is fixed by setting **setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.UTF-8")**. So It is all great now, thank you!